# jQuery - .appendTo a specific part of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery object (named `wid`) that has a code similar to this:

```
<li class='widget'>
    <div class='widget-head'>
        <h3>head</h3></div>
    <div class='widget-content'>
        <p>LINE1</p>
        <p>LINE2</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

I want to append `<p>LINE3</p>` after the last line of the content. Currently I'm doing this:

```
var content = $('.widget-content');
var $newItem = $('<p>LINE3</p>').appendTo($(content).last(), wid);
```

but the problem is that it appends the line to the last line of the last gadget (not `wid`). How can I make it append to the last line of the `wid` and not the last widget?

Comment: Can you please provide a jsFiddle showing the code you have above?

Comment: Just `$( '.widget-content' ).append( '<p>LINE3</p>' );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var content = $('.widget-content', wid); //or beter wid.find('.widget-content');
var $newItem = $('<p>LINE3</p>').appendTo(content);
```

You missplaced context - it should be in `content` query. Also, you dont have to wrap again content into jq object, and assuming you have only one content in widget, you dont have to use `last`.

Comment: For some reason `wid.find()` didn't work but `$('.widget-content', wid)` did. Thank you.

Comment: Cool, but i'm wondering why `find` didn't worked. you're sure `wid` is jQuery object, not bare html element? - Maybe look at it with firebug or something - simple `console.log(wid)` should show you what sits there :)

Answer (score 3):

Try following:

```
$('<p>LINE3</p>').appendTo(wid.find('.widget-content'));
```

According to documentation [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) doesnt' have overloaded function with 2 params.